# Getting Error converting data type varchar to numeric, why is this on Line 1

Tags: sql, varchar

Hello I am trying to use case statement to do multiplications. Why is it line 1?

Got error below when trying to set up case statement:
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

```
SELECT 
GIFT.ID AS GIFT_ID,
RECORDS.CONSTITUENT_ID AS Constit_ID,
RECORDS.FIRST_NAME + ' ' + RECORDS.LAST_NAME AS Constit_Name,
RECORDS.ORG_NAME AS Constit_Org_Name,
GIFT.Amount AS Gift_Amount,
GIFT.DATE_1ST_PAY AS Schedule_Start_Date, 
GIFT.Schedule_EndDate AS Scheule_End_Date,
GIFT.NextTransactionDate AS Next_Transaction_Date,
GIFT.TYPE AS Gift_Type,
GIFT_1.Amount AS Recurring_Gift_Amount,
CASE DBO.Query_GetFrequency(GIFT.TYPE,GIFT.ID,GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Annually'  WHEN 2 THEN 'Semi-Annually'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Quarterly' WHEN 4 THEN 'Bimonthly'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Monthly'   WHEN 6 THEN 'Semi-Monthly'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Biweekly'  WHEN 8 THEN 'Weekly'
    WHEN 9 THEN 'Irregular' WHEN 10 THEN 'Single Installment'
    ELSE '' END Gift_Installment_Frequency_Descrip,
GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY AS Installment_Freq_Code,

-- Case statement for the different installment frequencies

CASE 
    WHEN GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY = 1 -- Annually
        THEN (GIFT_1.Amount * 1)
    WHEN GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY = 2 -- Semi-Annually
        THEN (GIFT_1.Amount * 2)
    ELSE ' ' END Payment


FROM RECORDS
INNER JOIN GIFT ON RECORDS.ID = GIFT.CONSTIT_ID
INNER JOIN RecurringGiftActivity ON GIFT.ID = RecurringGiftActivity.RecurringGiftId
INNER JOIN GIFT AS GIFT_1 ON RecurringGiftActivity.PaymentId = GIFT_1.ID

WHERE GIFT.TYPE = 30 -- Gift type 30 = recurring gift
ORDER BY GIFT.ID
```

Comment: CASE 
    WHEN GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY = 1 -- Annually
        THEN (GIFT_1.Amount * 1)
    WHEN GIFT.INSTALLMENT_FREQUENCY = 2 -- Semi-Annually
        THEN (GIFT_1.Amount * 2)
    ELSE ' ' END Payment      looks suspicious. Could you please try ELSE 0.00 END AS Payments

Comment: A case expression returns a single scalar value of a known type, if your code paths return different data types, they will be implcitely cast using data type precedence; `' '` is not a valid numeric value, hence your error.

Comment: I am very new to SQL, thank you for the error troubleshooting!